# Android: How to change CheckBox size?

Tags: android, checkbox

I would like to make CheckBox a bit smaller/bigger, how can I do this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You just need to set the related drawables and set them in the checkbox:

```
<CheckBox 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="new checkbox" 
    android:background="@drawable/my_checkbox_background"
    android:button="@drawable/my_checkbox" />
```

The trick is on how to set the drawables. [Here's a good tutorial about this](http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_change_look_of_checkbox-t4553.html).

Comment: Keep in mind that different devices may have custom themes installed.  If you adjust the size by placing your own custom image, make sure you replace every checkbox in the app (even if there is no size change) or else you may end up with a mix of styles on certain devices.

Comment: The Link is broken

Answer (score 168):

Starting with API Level 11 there is another approach exists:

```
<CheckBox
    ...
    android:scaleX="0.70"
    android:scaleY="0.70"
/>
```

Comment: This technique will also scale the text label. To compensate for this, I adjusted the text size as follows                     checkBox.TextSize = (int)(TEXT_SIZE/SCALE_FACTOR);

Comment: If I do this to increase, e.g. scale it to "2.0" then it does get larger, but the image is clipped, I see the right half of the checkbox and the left half of the text. Any way around this?

Comment: nice, it still takes the same space though. To solve that i used -ve margins, like:  android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"

Comment: I will probably not be shown in the IDE's preview, but CheckBox will be scaled in run time

Comment: Shows in AS Design view for me. Simple fix for something that shouldn't need a fix.I think the API or device affects. using Gennymotion device at API 22 it appears that 0.8 is the highest Y (horizontal LinearLayout), whilst el cheapo, Onix Tablet doesn't clip at 1.

Comment: This worked for me adjusting the size of checkbox...really helpful,Thanks alex2k8

Answer (score 113):

Here is a better solution which does not clip and/or blur the drawable, but only works if the checkbox doesn't have text itself (but you can still have text, it's just more complicated, see at the end).

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/item_switch"
    android:layout_width="160dp"    <!-- This is the size you want -->
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:button="@null"
    android:background="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"/>
```

The result:

> [image]

What the previous solution with `scaleX` and `scaleY` looked like:

> [image]

You can have a text checkbox by adding a `TextView` beside it and adding a click listener on the parent layout, then triggering the checkbox programmatically.

Comment: Using background doesn't work if your checkbox has text.

Comment: @ZachGreen yes indeed. Didn't think of the possibility that it would not work if the checkbox had text, mine hadn't. Will update the answer

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted one.

Comment: at 160dp looks like grainy. Seems that is at too low resolution

Comment: how do I set tint for such checkbox?

Comment: if you need to change the color of a checkbox, create new style and set there desired `colorAccent`. Then set the style as a theme to the checkbox `android:theme="@style/customCheckboxColor"`

Comment: seems blurry :(

Comment: To change the tint color use android:backgroundTint="#3e97e9"

Answer (score 26):

Well i have found many answer, But they work fine without text when we require text also with checkbox like in my UI[image]

Here as per my UI requirement i can't not increase TextSize so other option i tried is scaleX and scaleY (Strach the check box) and custom xml selector with .png Images(its also creating problem with different screen size)

> But we have another solution for that, that is **Vector Drawable**

Do it in 3 steps.

**Step 1:** Copy these three Vector Drawable to your drawable folder

checked.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="16dp"
android:height="16dp"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:viewportWidth="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M19,3L5,3c-1.11,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v14c0,1.1 0.89,2 2,2h14c1.11,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L21,5c0,-1.1 -0.89,-2 -2,-2zM10,17l-5,-5 1.41,-1.41L10,14.17l7.59,-7.59L19,8l-9,9z" />
</vector>
```

un_checked.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="16dp"
android:height="16dp"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:viewportWidth="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M19,5v14H5V5h14m0,-2H5c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v14c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V5c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2z" />
</vector>
```

(*Note if you are workiong with Android Studio, you can also add these Vector Drawable from there, Right click on your drawable folder then New/Vector Asset, then select these drawable from there*)

**Step 2:** Create XML selector for check_box

check_box_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checked" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/un_checked" />
</selector>
```

**Step 3:** Set that drawable into check box

```
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/suggectionNeverAskAgainCheckBox"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:button="@drawable/check_box_selector"
android:textColor="#FF000000"
android:textSize="13dp"
android:text="  Never show this alert again" />
```

Now its like:

[image]

---

> You can change its width and height or viewportHeight and viewportWidth
>   and fillColor also

---

Hope it will help!

Comment: In my case i had to set `android:button="@null"` and `android:background="@drawable/check_box_selector"` to make it adjust the checkbox size.

Comment: this approach breaks paddings

Answer (score 12):

I use

`android:scaleX="0.70"
android:scaleY="0.70"`

to ajust the size of checkbox

then I set margins like this

```
android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
```

to adjust ths location of the checkbox.

Comment: Bro, though it does size it down - margin does not work in my case. My checkbox images are 173 x 93 - the size of the checkbox still occupies that space. Antoine Bolvy is a more flexible solution to my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

You can try the following solution to change the size of `custom checkbox` by setting the following properties to `Checkbox` in your layout file. Worked for me

> android:scaleX="0.8"
>     android:scaleY="0.8"

```
android:button="@null"
android:scaleX="0.8"
android:scaleY="0.8"
android:background="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
```

add following lines to drawable file

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_checked="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked_img" />
<item android:state_checked="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/checked_img" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 6):

Here was what I did, first set:

`android:button="@null"`

and also set

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/selector_you_defined_for_your_checkbox"
```

then in your Java code:

```
Drawable d = mCheckBox.getCompoundDrawables()[0];
d.setBounds(0, 0, width_you_prefer, height_you_prefer);
mCheckBox.setCompoundDrawables(d, null, null, null);
```

It works for me, and hopefully it will work for you!

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: this only works from API 17 onwards...

---

To add to the other brilliant answers already given, you can only make the checkbox as small as the text size allows.

As per my answer on this question:
 - [how can we reduce the size of checkbox please give me an idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13760524/383414)

---

`CheckBox` derives its height from the TEXT as well as the image.

Set these properties in your XML:

```
android:text=""
android:textSize="0sp"
```

Of course this only works if you want no text (worked for me).

Without these changes, the `CheckBox` was giving me a big margin around my image, as mentioned by Joe

Answer (score 2):

use this code.

in layout:

```
<CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/my_checkbox"  *** here
        android:checked="true"/>
```

add a new drawable :  my_checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:state_checked="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off_background"/>

<item
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on_background"/>
```

and end create 2 drawable :

checkbox_off_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
            android:height="25dp"   *** your size
            android:width="25dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:drawable="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background"/>
```

and too, checkbox_on_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
            android:height="25dp"
            android:width="25dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:drawable="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not find the relevant answer for my requirement which I figured it out. So, this answer is for checkbox with text like below where you want to resize the checkbox drawable and text separately.

[image]

You need two PNGs cb_checked.png and cb_unchechecked.png add them to drawable folder

Now create cb_bg_checked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cb_checked"
        android:height="22dp" <!-- This is the size of your checkbox -->
        android:width="22dp"  <!-- This is the size of your checkbox -->
        android:right="6dp"   <!-- This is the padding between cb and text -->
        tools:targetApi="m"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
</layer-list>
```

And, cb_bg_unchecked.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/cb_unchechecked"
            android:height="22dp" <!-- This is the size of your checkbox -->
            android:width="22dp"  <!-- This is the size of your checkbox -->
            android:right="6dp"   <!-- This is the padding between cb and text -->
            tools:targetApi="m"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
    </layer-list>
```

Then create a selector XML checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cb_bg_checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cb_bg_unchecked" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Now define it your layout.xml like this

```
<CheckBox
  android:id="@+id/checkbox_with_text"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:checked="true"
  android:button="@drawable/checkbox"
  android:text="This is text"
  android:textColor="@color/white"
  android:textSize="14dp" /> <!-- Here you can resize text -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it without creating your own images.  In other words, the system image is being scaled.  I don't pretend that the solution is perfect; if anyone knows a way to shorten some of the steps, I'll be happy to find out how.

First, I put the following in the main activity class of the project (WonActivity) .  This was taken directly from Stack Overflow -- **thank you guys**!

```
/** get the default drawable for the check box */
Drawable getDefaultCheckBoxDrawable()
{
  int resID = 0;

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10)
  {
    // pre-Honeycomb has a different way of setting the CheckBox button drawable
    resID = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("btn_check", "drawable", "android");
  }
  else
  {
    // starting with Honeycomb, retrieve the theme-based indicator as CheckBox button drawable
    TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    getApplicationContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple, value, true);
    resID = value.resourceId;
  }

  return getResources().getDrawable(resID);
}
```

Second, I created a class to "scale a drawable".  Please notice that it is completely different from the standard ScaleDrawable.

```
import android.graphics.drawable.*;

/** The drawable that scales the contained drawable */

public class ScalingDrawable extends LayerDrawable
{
  /** X scale */
  float scaleX;

  /** Y scale */
  float scaleY;

  ScalingDrawable(Drawable d, float scaleX, float scaleY)
  {
    super(new Drawable[] { d });
    setScale(scaleX, scaleY);
  }

  ScalingDrawable(Drawable d, float scale)
  {
    this(d, scale, scale);
  }

  /** set the scales */
  void setScale(float scaleX, float scaleY)
  {
    this.scaleX = scaleX;
    this.scaleY = scaleY;
  }

  /** set the scale -- proportional scaling */
  void setScale(float scale)
  {
    setScale(scale, scale);
  }

  // The following is what I wrote this for!

  @Override
  public int getIntrinsicWidth()
  {
    return (int)(super.getIntrinsicWidth() * scaleX);
  }

  @Override
  public int getIntrinsicHeight()
  {
    return (int)(super.getIntrinsicHeight() * scaleY);
  }
}
```

Finally, I defined a checkbox class.

```
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.widget.*;

/** A check box that resizes itself */

public class WonCheckBox extends CheckBox
{
  /** the check image */
  private ScalingDrawable checkImg;

  /** original height of the check-box image */
  private int origHeight;

  /** original padding-left */
  private int origPadLeft;

  /** height set by the user directly */
  private float height;

  WonCheckBox()
  {
    super(WonActivity.W.getApplicationContext());
    setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    // get the original drawable and get its height
    Drawable origImg = WonActivity.W.getDefaultCheckBoxDrawable();
    origHeight = height = origImg.getIntrinsicHeight();
    origPadLeft = getPaddingLeft();

    // I tried origImg.mutate(), but that fails on Android 2.1 (NullPointerException)
    checkImg = new ScalingDrawable(origImg, 1);
    setButtonDrawable(checkImg);
  }

  /** set checkbox height in pixels directly */
  public void setHeight(int height)
  {
    this.height = height;
    float scale = (float)height / origHeight;
    checkImg.setScale(scale);

    // Make sure the text is not overlapping with the image.
    // This is unnecessary on Android 4.2.2, but very important on previous versions.
    setPadding((int)(scale * origPadLeft), 0, 0, 0);

    // call the checkbox's internal setHeight()
    //   (may be unnecessary in your case)
    super.setHeight(height);
  }
}
```

That's it.  If you put a WonCheckBox in your view and apply setHeight(), the check-box image will be of the right size.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your original xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tick_img" />
    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/untick_img" />
</selector>
```

then simply remove `android:button="@drawable/xml_above"` in your checkbox xml, and do drawable scaling programmatically in java (decrease the `150` big size to your desired dp):

```
CheckBox tickRememberPasswd = findViewById(R.id.remember_tick);

//custom selector size
Drawable drawableTick = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.tick_img);
Drawable drawableUntick = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.untick_img);
Bitmap bitmapTick = null;
if (drawableTick != null && drawableUntick != null) {
    int desiredPixels = Math.round(convertDpToPixel(150, this));

    bitmapTick = ((BitmapDrawable) drawableTick).getBitmap();
    Drawable dTick = new BitmapDrawable(getResources()
            , Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapTick, desiredPixels, desiredPixels, true));

    Bitmap bitmapUntick = ((BitmapDrawable) drawableUntick).getBitmap();
    Drawable dUntick = new BitmapDrawable(getResources()
            , Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapUntick, desiredPixels, desiredPixels, true));

    final StateListDrawable statesTick = new StateListDrawable();
    statesTick.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_checked},
            dTick);
    statesTick.addState(new int[] { }, //else state_checked false
            dUntick);
    tickRememberPasswd.setButtonDrawable(statesTick);
}
```

the `convertDpToPixel` method:

```
public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a custom image to checkbox then
set button to null and just add background to checkbox
that's solve

```
 <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="22dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
    android:button="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/memory_selector"/>
```