# Increasing the size of Checkbox

Tags: android

I want to increase the size of checkboxes in honeycomb, Is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks,
Manan

Comment: Take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151241/android-how-to-change-checkbox-size