# How to change the size of the button of an android checkbox?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, bitmap

I changed the Bitmaps of an Android 2.3.4 Checkbox and would like to set the size of the bitmaps to scale them. I changed the checkbox like this:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb1"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sort: 1" />
```

with the matching xml drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"  android:state_focused="true"    android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on_background_focus_yellow"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"    android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off_background_focus_yellow"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off_background" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on_background" />
</selector>
```

How can I set a dip/dp value to change the size of the bitmaps of the checkbox ?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58272110/28557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by making the bitmaps the right size. I cannot scale it now but I tested it on several devices with varying dpi settings and it seems fine. For now.

Answer (score 14):

Actually what you could've done to set an image to the size of the checkbox is to put

```
android:button="@null"
android:background="@drawable/checkbox" <!-- your custom selector -->
```

With this, your custom checkbox image (in both states, checked and unchecked) will always fit to the size of your checkbox.

Comment: And `android:backgroundTint="@color/checkbox_selector"`

Answer (score 0):

Just define related Drawables and set them into your checkbox properties.

```
android:background="@drawable/my_background"
```

Comment: I do not know what you mean, could you please be a little more precise?