# MULTICHOICE ListView CheckMarks Size

Tags: android, listview

How can I edit the size of the ListView's Checkmarks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkmark is a picture.Set another image of checkmark.

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151241/android-how-to-change-checkbox-size