# expandable list view checkbox smaller

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview

Here I have a expandable list view

[image]

now i put a Checkbox in it in the childs below

[image]

and my childview grow bigger - why and how can I set it smaller?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/mb">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="23dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Here, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151241/android-how-to-change-checkbox-size  I think the trick is to use `wrap_content` for the layout width and height for the checkbox.

Comment: nothing works until now - a custom Checkbox hmmm, maybe there is another easy way

Comment: Your using normal check boxes right?

Comment: Yes I do ......................

Comment: Try to resize the `dp` on both the `layout_height` and `layout_width`  like this: ` android:layout_width ="1dp"`  or whatever size you want it.

Comment: Yeah - you are my hero :)) - 1dp / 1dp they are vanished ;) - but width 40 height 20 will do the trick - thanks for this

Comment: Glad to have helped :) I put an answer below, it would be helpful for me and others if you accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `dp` on the `layout_height` and `layout_width` of the checkbox(or really anything else) to get the size you need.  For example:

```
<Checkbox
 android:layout_width="1dp"
 android:layout_height="1dp"
 android:id="@+id/checkBox"/>
```

in the item you wish to re-size.

Another option is to use custom check boxes, more info here: [Android: How to change CheckBox size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151241/android-how-to-change-checkbox-size)