# How can I change the border thickness of an Android checkbox?

Tags: android, checkbox, styles, thickness

The default size of the android checkboxes were too small for my purposes, so I changed their overall size, however with their new size their borders now are horribly thick.

In what way could I change the thickness? I quite like the default behavior of the checkboxes, so the only thing I would like to change is the thickness of the border.

Code used to make the checkbox larger:

```
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/item_switch"
android:layout_width="160dp"    
android:layout_height="160dp"
android:button="@null"
android:background="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"/>
```

From this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36071778/7089738).

Comment: Can u provide your checkbox xml code?

Comment: I updated the OP.

Comment: Use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

So your code should look

```
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/item_switch"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:button="@null"
android:background="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"/>
```

Comment: Right, except now the button has the default size, which brings me back to square one. I need the button to be both bigger (160dp in width and height) and have reduced border thickness.

Comment: I mean that I want to style the button so that it is both bigger and doesn't have such thick borders when it is bigger.

Comment: @user7089738 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346727/android-material-design-button-styles?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Am I correct in concluding that I will have to make my own custom images for the checkbox to get the look I want?