# How to change checkbox background color to match my theme color?

Tags: android, react-native, checkbox

I can not figure out how to change the background color of a checkbox in react native? I am from frontend background and have pretty little knowledge on Android. I am using react native CheckBox component and am not using any libraries for this purpose.

Comment: Let see this links and follow the steps given here.
1)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930297/how-to-change-background-of-android-checkbox 2)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854047/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-checkbox/36635925

Comment: I believe these solutions work. But they are speaking in some foreign language. Can the solution be interpreted in React Nativeish way? :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this to change backgroud color of checkbox component

```
 <View style={{ backgroundColor:this.state.checked? 'red':'white'}}>
      <CheckBox value={this.state.checked} this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked }) />
 </View>
```

Try to change change code natively

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:buttonTint="@color/CHECK_COLOR" />
```

for v7 older API levels:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    app:buttonTint="@color/COLOR_HERE" />
```

Comment: This makes the whole view background red. I want to change the background of checkbox only when the checkbox is checked. Now, checkbox background is green when checked.

Comment: you can use a custom view for checkbox and change it color programmatically when checked

Comment: No any props for backgroud color its should be render on view or any other container ( https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/checkbox )

Comment: Yeah, there are no props for background color. Changing the view container does not give the desired result. Did the solution work on your end?

Comment: try @SurendraPathak

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186643/discussion-between-niroshan-ranapathi-and-surendra-pathak).

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that if you have view you can use

```
int color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
Drawable background = view.getBackground();
if (background instanceof ColorDrawable)
color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();
```

or you can use color palettes

https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-usage-palettes